# could not open tablespace directory "pg_tblspc/132528327/PG_9.1_201105231" while cold backup restoration which is having two different tablespace

Tags: backup, postgresql-9.1, database-backups, tablespace

I'am facing an problem while restoring and recovering of cold backup with WALS. Actually my database storage as two tablespace. I have created one seperate tablespace located in another disk which takes data from it ie., tables which are in other tablespace not default tablespace. I'am getting error while restoring the cold backup into another server like below:-

> could not open tablespace directory "pg_tblspc/132528327/PG_9.1_201105231": No such file or directory.

Actually the server is up and running fine after recovery completion with archives but the data changes which are in different tablespace not recovered only restored data is coming. Please advice how to apply archives (WALS) on the tables which are in different tablespace of different storage.

Answer (score 0):

WAL recovery assumes you have the same starting out point for your data directory in including tables, tablespaces, etc.  If you have lost a tablespace before applying your wal segments, you need to see what you can do to get the right database backup.  If this was missed, you will not be able to restore data that was initially in the table.

Data which is in the WAL may be recoverable by a real expert but it will not likely be complete.

In other words, go back and look at your backups again.